# How to print file. PRN with PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a system that at the time I need to print files `.PRN`.

It is the following situation:

I have a web system (1) in PHP, a desktop system (2) and INTEGRA (responsible for integration between the two systems).

How do it works that communication between systems 1 and 2?

I uploaded an XML request for a file with extension `.TX` for INTEGRA that forwards to the system 2. The same processes the information and returns an XML response file with extension `.RX` and other `.PRN.`

If the system were to use only 2, as that is the treatment done?

It generates a file `.PRN` that is related to a physical label and sends it to the printer. The label printer interprets all those crazy codes and performs printing. It simply sends the file `.PRN`, no need to do any manipulation.

With this integration printing the labels will not be performed by the system but by 2, but at 1. As this process of communication system 1 <-> INTEGRA <-> System 2, the system 1 receives a `.RX and a .PRN` file, I need to print this PRN...

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Do you mean actually print the file using PHP? I would have thought the only way to do that would be to shell_exec a command to print

Comment: Practically this ... I need to get a file .PRN and send it to be printed on a printer barcode ... I have to do this in PHP.

Comment: What OS is your PHP running on. I assume the PHP script is running on the hardware that the printer is connected to?

Comment: PHP script isn't running on the hardware that the printer is connected to?

Comment: OK I'm sorry but you aren't giving us anything to go on here to provide an answer. Where is the printer, what is it connected to, what operating system and network connectivity does that device have..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when u get prn file

```
                                         $output = shell_exec('COPY /B barcode.prn \"\\your system name\SATO SA408\"');
```